# Same memory address for more than 1 byte object in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, byte, memory-address

If a memory address references 1 byte of memory, how does the memory address of say '139754451527680' for an empty list stay the same if I append elements to that list?

To clarify, I understand that elements of an array/list are pointers to the elements location, etc...

My question is specific to if the memory address is the address of 1 byte of memory, how does the address 'get calculated' for larger than 1 byte objects?

Is it just the (memory address * 8) if we are talking about an 8 byte object?

```
import sys
a = 1
sys.getsizeof(a)  # 28 bytes (24 bytes int overhead; 4 bytes integer value)
id(a)             # 9788960  ---> 28 memory slot / memory addresses????
```

Comment: Think of an address as just a pointer that points to the beginning of the array. It will remain the same irrespective of the size. Python has no pointer manipulation though.

Comment: Makes sense, but to add, pointers in Python are 8 bytes; so in the output of the id() method, the address returned is the memory address of the first byte?